# How to get ropsten test token?

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, nodejs

Please help me!. to found out the ropsten test token on the eth address,

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ropsten test ether, you can get it from faucets like,
http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/ or https://faucet.metamask.io/

**EDIT:** Metamask faucet is not working properly but http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/ is working fine.